# Ajax : call a boolean Action

Tags: c#, ajax, boolean

I want to get a boolean value from an Action and make a test according to the return value in the corresponding AJAX function.

I've put a breakpoint on the Action but my submission passes without calling the Action.

Here is my Action:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public Boolean VerifyEmailExist(string email)
{
    if(db.UtilisateurSet.Where( p => p.Utilisateur_EmailPrinc == email).ToList().Count() != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my AJAX method:

```
function VerifyEmailExist(champ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Utilisateur/VerifyEmailExist",
        type: 'Get',
        data: {
            email: champ,
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                champ.style.backgroundColor = "#fba";
                alert("Votre Email Existe dèja!");
                return false;
            } else {
                champ.style.backgroundColor = "";
                return true;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("something seems wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't return a boolean result, return type must inherit ActionResult. You can return JsonResult:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult VerifyEmailExist(string email)
{
    if(db.UtilisateurSet.Where( p => p.Utilisateur_EmailPrinc == email).ToList().Count() != 0)
    {
        return Json(new { status = false });
    }

    else
    {
        return Json(new { status = true });
    }
}
```

And ur ajax success event:

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response.status) {
       champ.style.backgroundColor = "#fba";
       alert("Votre Email Existe dèja!");
       return false;
    } else {
       champ.style.backgroundColor = "";
       return true;
    }
 },
```

Comment: i've made this changes, but even i use an actionResult Method, the Ajax can't get to it !!